# Find $\frac{\ln(n!)}{n^n}$ by squeeze theorem

Tags: limits

How to find $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(n!)}{n^n}$ by squeeze theorem? Surely there's a simple way but I couldn't spot it.

Comment: $$0 < n! < n^n$$

Answer (score 5):

We use these inequalities

$$\frac{1}{n^n}\le\frac{\ln(n!)}{n^n}\le\frac{n\ln n}{n^n}=\frac{\ln n}{n^{n-1}}\le\frac1{n^{n-2}}$$

Comment: Might want to extend by $< \frac{1}{n ^{n-2}}$.

Comment: Easy, simple to get

Comment: Nice suggestion! @EricTowers

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound is obviously $0$, for the upper bound compare the numerator to $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log k \leq 1 +\int_{1}^{n} \log x dx  = 1 +(n-1) \log n $ which obviously tends  to $0$ when you divide it by $n^n$.